# django: passing custom tag a parameter

Tags: python, django, templatetag

I'm trying to pass a variable from the URL (not the query string) to a custom tag, but it looks like I'm getting a ValueError when converting it to an int.  It appears at first glance that it's coming in as a string like "project.id" instead of the actual integer value of that.  From what I understand, the tag parameters are always strings.  If I print out the value of the parameter in my view before sending it down, it appears correct.  It might just be a string, but I figured that shouldn't matter if the template is going to convert it to an int anyway, right?

```
# in urls.py
# (r'^projects/(?P<projectId>[0-9]+)/proposal', proposal_editor),
# projectId sent down in RequestContext as 'projectId'

# in template
# {% proposal_html projectId %}

# in templatetag file
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.tag(name="proposal_html")
def do_proposal_html(parser, token):
    try:
        # split_contents() knows not to split quoted strings.
    tagName, projectId = token.split_contents()
    except ValueError:
        raise template.TemplateSyntaxError, "%r tag requires a single argument" % token.contents.split()[0]
    print(projectId)
    projectId = int(projectId)

    return ProposalHtmlNode(int(projectId))

class ProposalHtmlNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, projectId):
    self.projectId = projectId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simply that you haven't resolved the variables to the values they contain. If you put some logging into your method, you'll see that at that point `projectId` is actually the string `"projectId"`, because that's how you referenced it in the template. You need to define this is an instance of `template.Variable` and then resolve it in the `Node`'s `render` method. See [the documentation on resolving variables](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#passing-template-variables-to-the-tag).

However, depending on what you're actually doing in `render`, you may find it easier to get rid of the Node class altogether and just use the [`simple_tag` decorator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#shortcut-for-simple-tags), which as well as not needing a separate Node also gets the variables already resolved as its parameters.